# Can't trace XML Data?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

Hello I am trying to trace some XML Data. I used a URLLoader and once load is complete, I try to trace back the XML Data. I can trace the entire file

```
trace(xmlData);
```

but if I try to trace a specific node, I get nothing in my trace

```
trace(xmlData.captions);
```

What could I be doing wrong? All tutorials I've seen make this seem so straight forward, but it's just not working for me?

//////EDIT////

here is the question clarified.

```
protected var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
public var xmlData:XML = new XML();

public function loadXML(_filename:String) {
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadIt);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(_filename));          
}

function loadIt(e:Event):void {
xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
parseData(xmlData);
}
function parseData(input:XML):void {
    trace(xmlData.captions);
}
```

If I just do trace(xmlData); I see everything fine. It's when I add the .captions that I get a blank trace.

here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<captions>
    <cap start="00:01.7">
Narrator: Someone watching a car
    <br/>
    accelerate toward light speed
</cap>
<cap start="00:05.0">
    would see something
    <br/>
    very strange.
</cap>
</captions>
```

Comment: Add more details, the loading code, what gets traced and the xml itself

Answer (score 4):

It's because `<captions>` is your so called root node. So when you try parsing `input.captions` you actually search for `captions.captions`. Parsing the children of your root node can be done similar to what you've already tried:

```
function parseData(input:XML):void 
{    
    // xml list of your cap attributes
    trace(input.cap);

    for (var i : int = 0; i < input.children().length(); i++) 
    {
       // every child node within your captions root node
       trace(input.children()[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but you got the var name wrong inside your function xmlData should be input

Answer (score 1):

As @rvmool said, `captions` is the root node so it does not exist in the XML object.

Plus, don't forget to use `toXMLString()` when you wish to trace an XML's content.

```
trace(xmlData.cap.toXMLString());
```